# How to safely dispose a laptop?

Tags: laptop

If I remove the hard drive from the laptop, does it suffice to say that noone who has his/her hands on my laptop would be able to have access to my personal information ?

Are there any other parts that I shall also remove ?

Comment: In most cases that should be sufficient but also depends on what you consider personal information.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the hard drive is more than adequate, 
don't forget to remove any SD cards too.